# rbenv command not found on Mac OS

Tags: ruby, macos, rbenv, rbenv-gemset, rbenv-vars

We are trying to run rbenv on El-Capitan 10.11.6. When we try to run rbenv command in the terminal we got the following error message:

```
command not found
```

We googled how to solve that issue and one possible solution is to add the "rbenv" to the system PATH, we followed the steps stated in [this link](http://architectryan.com/2012/10/02/add-to-the-path-on-mac-os-x-mountain-lion/#.WUvUPUX5yL9). When we run the "$PATH" to check whether or not the rbenv path was added properly into the system PATH, we got the the same result:

```
command not found
```

The result of  "$PATH" command is:

```
qwe-Mac-mini:~ amrbakri$ rbenv

-bash: rbenv: command not found
qwe-Mac-mini:~ asd$ echo $PATH    

/Users/asd/.rbenv/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/MacGPG2/bin
```

Can you please tell me how to add the path of rbenv properly? And what did I do wrong in the previous steps so that I can fix it.

Comment: Did you restart the shell after that... ```exec -l $SHELL```

Comment: i am using the regular terminal in mac, and yes the shell was restarted..do you have any suggestions??

Comment: Can you paste your ~/.bash_profile file contents here

Comment: the path looks fine. have you checked `/Users/asd/.rbenv/bin` to see that the directory exists and that `rbenv` is within?

Comment: Did you add `eval "$(rbenv init -)"` to your `~/.bash_profile` ?

Answer (score 0):

`rbenv` isn't a normal command if you've installed it correctly:

```
$ type rbenv
rbenv is a function
. . .
```

According to [Homebrew on Mac OS X](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv#homebrew-on-mac-os-x):

> You'll only ever have to run `rbenv init` once.

That's a bit misleading because the result of running the command is:

```
$ rbenv init
# Load rbenv automatically by appending
# the following to ~/.bash_profile:

eval "$(rbenv init -)"
```

So you need to manually add `eval "$(rbenv init -)"` to some file that [bash will source on startup](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html). For most people ~/.bash_profile is the right place.

I notice the commands you listed seem to be run from two different users: amrbakri and asd. Combined with the question's use of "we", I wonder if there might be a problem with the environment being set correctly for one user, but not the other. Can you try using just one user?

If you are running from a non-interactive shell (such as [in a crontab](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44448510/7948068)), you might need to add `eval "$(rbenv init -)"` to the startup script.

Answer (score 0):

I following the instructions about "bash" command, then do the "eval" operation.

I'm in MacOS 11.2.3, in your .bash_profile, add the two lines.

`export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"#this is the required step for my mac`

`eval "$(rbenv init -)"`

refer: https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv#homebrew-on-mac-os-x